# Xamarin.Droid HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin Forms.  I am building an app which consumes a web service.  I am getting `HttpRequestException` while trying to connect to server.  The InnerException throws `System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)`.

The code that crash is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Bono>> GetAll()
{
    var Url = Constants.baseUrl + "cliente/1/bonos";
    HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
    var bonos = await cliente.GetStringAsync(Url);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bono>>(bonos);
}
```

I am using VS for Mac.  The same works for Xamarin.iOS.  Any suggestion on this?

Comment: `NameResolutionFailure` Whatever your `Constants.baseUrl` points to is not being resolved.

Comment: I'm consuming that service using Postman, and it works when I run Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Can you browse that host from the Android's​ browser? And what http client implementation is your Android project set to in your build settings?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: you open the browser on the device/emulator and type in the url for your service.  If it can't connect then you have an underlying connectivity issue.

Comment: I tested it and I'm getting NAME_NOT_RESOLVE but why can I access it via Postman, iOS, and other browser?

Comment: I ended up deploying my API to Azure instead of localhost.  For some reason the problem was with localhost.  Working fine now

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint that you are trying to consume is hosted on your local machine and you are running the application in the local android emulator, you could use the following IP address to reach the host machine from the emulator:

```
http://10.0.2.2
```

Of course this will break iOS but it's the IP that can be used from an android emulator to access the host. As an alternative you could use [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) which can create a publicly accessible tunnel to an endpoint hosted on your local machine and then access the public endpoint from the android application. It could be helpful during development if you want to avoid hosting your endpoint to a network location that can be accessed from the emulator.